# Xilinx Vivado ERROR: [IP_Flow 19-343] User Parameter 't_dbs (T Dbs)': Default value "0,002" does not match format "float"

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado

The error `does not match format "float"` may occur on a system with a language setting which has a comma in float numbers (for instance, `2,3` instead of `2.3`). For example, it may occur in Vivado 20.2 on a Linux system. How to solve the error?

Answer (score 1):

On a Linux system, this error can be solved by switching to the default float format (for instance, 2.3): find the file `bin/vivado` of your vivado installation and open it with an editor. After the line

```
#!/bin/bash
```

paste the following code:

```
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8" 
export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"

LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: the non-exported variables do nothing because they are not exported. If they did, they would be redundant because LC_ALL overrides all the others.